# How do I get compass heading from DeviceOrientation in the Google Glass Browser?

Tags: javascript, html, compass-geolocation, google-glass

The web browser built into Google Glass as of firmware version XE7 provides [`DeviceOreientation` events](http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/), but the values don't seem to come from an expected frame of reference. How can one get proper compass headings out of this?  With Glass positioned normally on the head:

## DeviceOrientationEvent

### beta

```
     90  upright and level
    -90  inverted and level
      0  looking straight up or down
```

### gamma

```
     90  right ear towards floor
    180  looking straight up
270/-90  left ear down
      0  looking straight down
```

### alpha

*This property is not stable when Glass is horizontal (what should be the most useful orientation for using compass direction, to determine where the wearer is looking). It gives stable readings only when Glass is tilted well above or below the horizon.*

#### above horizontal

```
     90  North
      0  East
    180  West
    270  South
```

#### below horizontal

```
    270  North
    180  East
      0  West
     90  South
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get some idea on how to control the Compass from this newly launched [sample](https://github.com/googleglass/apk-compass-sample)